# Laravel app.js stops Stripe payment form from showing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cashier

I'm trying to accept payments with Stripe. I got the code from the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial)  and added it to a view. When I click the button it doesn't show the form, but instead goes to the form action page (payments).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="9HgWQfTsUXQ0RmIPQPLbhNoujOobjHn5PL9en8jx">

    <title>Staff</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="https://localhost/staff/public/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://localhost/staff/public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">



        <form action="payments/" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_xxx"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://localhost/staff/public/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I Stripped everything way down to eliminate everything a left only the button, still didn't work. One last thing to remove.....

```
<script src="https://localhost/staff/public/js/app.js"></script>
```

And that's what kept the form from showing....

So my question: Why would that be causing Stripe to not be able to show the form and what can I do to fix it? Did I just forget to set something up correctly? I'm new to Laravel, this is my first project with the framework, and my installation is pretty close to vanilla as I'm just getting started...

I ran `composer require "laravel/cashier":"~7.0"` and then added the service provider to config/app.php:

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider::class,
],
```

And then migrated the database.

Here are some of my files...

**web.php:**

```
...
Route::post('/payments', 'PaymentsController@subscribe')->name('payments');
Route::get('/payments', 'PaymentsController@index')->name('payments');
```

**PaymentsController.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Staff\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PaymentsController extends Controller
{

    //private $states;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index() {
        return view('payments/payment');
    }

    public function subscribe() {
        echo "huhh";

    }
}
```

**payment.blade.php:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_fCM9Fr1e33JYW6t17ZoSyXRf"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
@endsection
```

**services.php:**

```
<?php

return [

    ...

    'stripe' => [
        'model' => Staff\User::class,
        'key' => env('pk_test_xxx'),
        'secret' => env('sk_test_zzz'),
    ],

];
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. It's the logout form. If I remove that, the stripe form works.

```
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">{{ csrf_field() }}</form>
```

So, that means the two forms are conflicting. I added a name to the Stripe form, `stripe-form`, and updated the javascript

```
document.querySelector("form[name='stripe-form']").addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var form = document.querySelector("form[name='stripe-form']");
   var extraDetails = {
     name: form.querySelector('input[name=cardholder-name]').value,
   };
   stripe.createToken(card, extraDetails).then(setOutcome);
 });
```

Comment: Seems like it is enough to just add a name to the Stripe form.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, however giving the form a name and using the script you provided still doesn't cut it for my app. Temporally I removed app.js from the route that contains the Stripe button. Could there be another solution?

Comment: Same issue here.. Don't know how to resolve this issue